# How can I execute python module on Python3 if I encountered print without parants

Tags: python-3.x, pybrain

I want to launch pybrain tests on Python3 but I get error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "runtests.py", line 107, in <module>
        runner.run(make_test_suite())
      File "runtests.py", line 72, in make_test_suite
        test_package = __import__(test_package_path, fromlist=module_names)
      File "B:\msys64\mingw64\bin\WinPython\Python373\lib\site-packages\pybrain\tests\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from helpers import gradientCheck, buildAppropriateDataset, xmlInvariance, \
      File "B:\msys64\mingw64\bin\WinPython\Python373\Lib\site-packages\pybrain\tests\helpers.py", line 42
        print 'Module has no parameters'
                                   ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('Module has no parameters')?
```

I looked helpers.py and found that prints are without parents(as operators, I think it was in Python2).How can I fix that?Can I import some module to
execute with such problem, for example six, but I don t know what it does.

Comment: there are tools that help you migrate from python2 to python3. if only the print statements are the problem, a simple `find` and `replace` in any editor might suffice.

Comment: also, if this code was written in python 2 and you just want to execute in python3, I would advise you not to do that. 
Even if the code executes, it may generate incorrect response.